FileSystemStorage location in the Codename One Simulator on a Mac
Can someone tell me the location of the Simulator FileSystemStorage on a Mac? I need to verify my outputstream. Thanks

It's under ~/.cn1 where ~ is your home directory. Notice it also includes the contents of the Storage API and as a result might include some other files.
